# ConnectivityManager setNetworkPreference() / getNetworkPreference(): How are they actually used?

Tags: android, connectivity

I'm trying to understand the details of the ConnectivityManager. I noticed there are methods setNetworkPreference() and getNetworkPreference(), but there are no details in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getNetworkPreference%28%29) about how they should be used, except that they accept/return an integer, respectively. There is also a constant called DEFAULT_NETWORK_PREFERENCE, but that doesn't really provide many hints. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right there is no documentation. If you grep in the source code for android, you see the following.

```
user@host:~/android/system/frameworks$ grep -r "setNetworkPreference" *
base/core/java/android/net/IConnectivityManager.aidl:    void setNetworkPreference(int pref);
base/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java:    public void setNetworkPreference(int preference) {
base/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java:            mService.setNetworkPreference(preference);
...
base/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/WifiCommand.java:                    connMgr.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
base/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/DataCommand.java:                    connMgr.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
base/services/java/com/android/server/ConnectivityService.java:    public void setNetworkPreference(int preference) {
```

From the above it looks like only `TYPE_WIFI` and `TYPE_MOBILE` are used for setting the preferred method of accessing the network.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this is somewhat helpful. So, in theory, I could use setNetworkPreference in an application to preferentially use a mobile data connection, even if wifi is available (since I assume the default is the vice versa).  I can't think of a good use case for that at the moment, but it at least satisfies my curiosity. This does open up a new curiosity though....svc, WifiCommand, and DataCommand. I might explore those next!

Answer (score 1):

One example to test network :

```
public static boolean checkStatus(Context context)
{
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if( wifi.isAvailable() || mobile.isAvailable())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "No network available");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not answering his question.

Comment: Thanks, chrisendymion, but I agree with wojci. My question is specifically about the two methods I wrote about. I understand most of the other methods in this class. I'm just trying to figure out if there is something useful about set|getNetworkPreference. Thanks.

Comment: As usual .. if something is not documented, you just have to look in the source code. ;-)

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But the source code for ConnectivityManager just shows that these methods call methods of the same name in IConnectivityManager. I don't seem to have the source for this interface. Do I need to pull it from some repo, or...?